# Toast is not showing in LWC in community

Tags: lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-getlistui

```
import { LightningElement, track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent'
import Lead_Object from '@salesforce/schema/Lead';
import {getPicklistValuesByRecordType } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import {showToast} from 'c/prmUtils';


export default class CgmBecomePartner extends LightningElement {
    
    @track isShowToast =false;
    @track message;
    @track successmessage;
    @track messageClass='';
    reasonToJoin;
    allCountries;    
    partnerTypeOptions;
    termAndCOndition;

    
    @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: Lead_Object, recordTypeId: '012400000001GDKAA2' })
    wiredOptions(data,error){
        if(data){           
            const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            
            if(obj.data){

                this.allCountries = obj.data.picklistFieldValues.Country_Picklist__c.values;
                this.allCountries.splice(0,0,{label:"--Select Country*--",value:""});

                this.partnerTypeOptions = obj.data.picklistFieldValues.Partner_Type__c.values;
                this.partnerTypeOptions.splice(0,0,{label:"--Select Partner Type*--",value:""});
            }
        }
        else{
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    handlePartnerChange(event) {        
        this.template.querySelector('.partnerType').value = event.detail.value;       
    }

    handleCountryChange(event){        
        this.template.querySelector('.countryCode').value =event.detail.value;
    }

    handleFirstName(event){        
        this.template.querySelector('.firstName').value =event.detail.value;
    }
    handleLastName(event){        
        this.template.querySelector('.lastName').value =event.detail.value;
    }
    handleCompany(event){        
        this.template.querySelector('.company').value =event.detail.value;
    }
    handleEmail(event){        
        this.template.querySelector('.email').value =event.detail.value;
    }
    handlePhone(event){        
        this.template.querySelector('.phone').value =event.detail.value;
    }
    handleWebsite(event){        
        this.template.querySelector('.url').value =event.detail.value;
    }
    street1='';
    street2='';
    handleStreet1(event){        
        this.street1 = event.detail.value;
    }
    handleStreet2(event){        
        this.street2 =event.detail.value;
    }
    handleCity(event){        
        this.template.querySelector('.city').value =event.detail.value;
    }
    handleState(event){        
        this.template.querySelector('.state').value = event.detail.value;
    }
    handlePostalCode(event){        
        this.template.querySelector('.postalCode').value = event.detail.value;
    }
    handleReasonToJoin(event){
        this.reasonToJoin=event.detail.value;
        this.template.querySelector('.joiningReason').value =this.reasonToJoin;
    }    
    checkTerm(event){
        this.termAndCOndition = event.detail.checked;
    }

    save(){
        try{
            if(this.validate() && this.reasonToJoin!==''){
                this.template.querySelector('.street').value = this.street1 +' '+this.street2;
                this.template.querySelector('.webtolead').submit();
            }
            else if(!this.termAndCOndition){   
                const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Application Error',
                    message: 'Something went wrong',
                    variant: 'error',
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(evt);                    
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        catch(e){
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

    validate(){
        let allValid1 = true,allValid2 = true;
        if(this.template.querySelector("lightning-input")){
            allValid1 = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
            .reduce((validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
                inputCmp.reportValidity();
                return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
            }, true);
        }
        if(this.template.querySelector("lightning-combobox")){
            allValid2 = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-combobox')]
            .reduce((validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
                inputCmp.reportValidity();
                return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
            }, true);
        }
        if(this.template.querySelector("lightning-textarea")){
            this.template.querySelector("lightning-textarea").showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
        }
        return allValid1 && allValid2;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hi Vishal, I am also facing the same issue. Toast messages are not being displayed in the community. How did you resolve this?